How is lookup of a type different when used for member declaration vs declaration of a local variable in a template?
Consider this example to illustrate that a nested type needs to be looked up via a dependent name, otherwise there'll be errors:
template <typename T>
struct base {
    struct  inner{};
};

template <typename T>
struct derived : base<T> {
    typename base<T>::inner ok;    // I
    inner a;    
    void bar() { inner b; }    
};

This sometimes comes across as surprise when transitioning to using templates (eg here). I know why I is the correct way (explained here). However, looking at the output of gcc I was wondering....
<source>:10:5: error: 'inner' does not name a type
   10 |     inner a;
      |     ^~~~~
<source>:10:5: note: (perhaps 'typename base<T>::inner' was intended)
<source>: In member function 'void derived<T>::bar()':
<source>:11:18: error: 'inner' was not declared in this scope
   11 |     void bar() { inner b; }
      |                  ^~~~~

Only for inner a; gcc provides a useful hint perhaps 'typename base<T>::inner' was intended. Why not for inner b; ?
Are there any namelook up, template instantiation rules, etc, that affect whether a compiler would suggest base<T>::bar in one case but not the other?
Clang has no hint in either case while all gcc versions I tried show similar output as above. I acknowledge that the question has a potentially lame "No" answer. I am not aware of any reason gcc would deliberately not output a useful hint. However, I am not fluent in all the details and might miss something obvious.

AFAIK there is no difference.  My guess is that in the class scope it can see the main template has an inner member so it suggest its.  In the function scope it gets access to all of the base and derived class since it is part of the complete-class context so you might mean something else.

@NathanOliver thats exactly it :) https://godbolt.org/z/MqTWfvPMz

@NathanOliver though I still dont understand why gcc misses to produce the hint. Examples like this one https://godbolt.org/z/nh5Exr73b make be believe the reason is just about gcc internals

That's not too surprising.  Once in the function the members of the derived class generally take precedence and since its sees there is a member with a very similar name I can see why it would suggest it.  It might be a "bug" but I can see the class body and the member function bodies as having different scopes GCC uses for its error suggestions.  Do note that non of this is mandated so the fact you get any suggestion is a plus.
